# wide to long data table transformation with variables in columns and rows

Tags: python, r, dataframe, data-manipulation, data-munging

I have a csv with multiple tables with variables stored in both rows and columns.
About this csv:

1. I'd want to go "wide" to "long"
2. There are multiple "data frames" in one csv
3. There are different types of variables for each "data frames"

---

```
> df3
     V1          V2    V3     V4      V5     V6      V7    V8
1   nyc 123 main st month      1       2      3       4     5
2   nyc 123 main st     x  58568  567567 567909   35876 56943
3   nyc 123 main st     y   5345    3673   3453    3467   788
4   nyc 123 main st     z  53223  563894 564456   32409 56155
5                                                            
6    la  63 main st month      1       2      3       4     5
7    la  63 main st     a  87035 7467456   3363     863 43673
8    la  63 main st     b    345     456    345     678   345
9    la  63 main st     c  86690 7467000   3018     185 43328
10                                                           
11   sf 953 main st month      1       2      3       4     5
12   sf 953 main st     x 457456    3455 345345   56457  3634
13   sf 953 main st     b   5345    3673   3453    3467   788
14   sf 953 main st     z 452111    -218 341892   52990  2846
```

---

```
> df4
18 city     address month      x       y      z       a     b       c
19  nyc 123 main st     1  58568    5345  53223    null  null    null
20  nyc 123 main st     2 567567    3673 563894    null  null    null
21  nyc 123 main st     3 567909    3453 564456    null  null    null
22  nyc 123 main st     4  35876    3467  32409    null  null    null
23  nyc 123 main st     5  56943     788  56155    null  null    null
24   la  63 main st     1   null    null   null   87035   345   86690
25   la  63 main st     2   null    null   null 7467456   456 7467000
26   la  63 main st     3   null    null   null    3363   345    3018
27   la  63 main st     4   null    null   null     863   678     185
28   la  63 main st     5   null    null   null   43673   345   43328
29   sf 953 main st     1 457456    null 452111    null  5345    null
30   sf 953 main st     2   3455    null   -218    null  3673    null
31   sf 953 main st     3 345345    null 341892    null  3453    null
32   sf 953 main st     4  56457    null  52990    null  3467    null
33   sf 953 main st     5   3634    null   2846    null   788    null
```

The top is the data I have, the bottom is the transformation I want.

I'm most comfortable in R but I'm practicing Python, so any approach works.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format), but I don't understand what multiple "data.frames" in one csv means. I suspect that means you will have to use multiple `read.csv` statements.

Comment: Look into `spread()` in the tidyr package.  And `bind_rows()` in the dplyr package.  I think they should achieve what you want.

Comment: It was very difficult to reconstruct `df3` from the printed data in the question. For the future, I suggest to provide the output of `dput()` with your questions. This helps others to answer your questions more quickly and to understand the structure of the content (types, classes, etc) which isn't visible from the printed output.

Answer (score 0):

It would help first if you had proper column names for your df, please insert column names once you read in the data.

I have use the following libraries, `dplyr` and `stringr` for this analysis and also renamed the first 3 columns:

```
df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
        city = c("nyc", "nyc", "nyc"),
     address = c("123 main st", "123 main st", "123 main st"),
       month = c("x", "y", "z"),
          X1 = c(58568L, 5345L, 53223L),
          X2 = c(567567L, 3673L, 563894L),
          X3 = c(567909L, 3453L, 564456L),
          X4 = c(35876L, 3467L, 32409L),
          X5 = c(56943L, 788L, 56155L)
)

df %>% gather(Type, Value, -c(city:month)) %>% 
        spread(month, Value) %>%
        mutate(month = str_sub(Type, 2, 2)) %>%
        select(-Type) %>%
        select(c(city, address, month, x:z))

city     address month      x    y      z
1  nyc 123 main st     1  58568 5345  53223
2  nyc 123 main st     2 567567 3673 563894
3  nyc 123 main st     3 567909 3453 564456
4  nyc 123 main st     4  35876 3467  32409
5  nyc 123 main st     5  56943  788  56155
```

Comment: The OP has asked to reshape multiple tables within his csv file. Your post only shows how to reshape *one* of the tables by deliberately making up your own simplified data set. How will you proceed to convert *all* tables in oder to make your post a complete answer?

Answer (score 0):

The sample data set provided by the OP suggests that all data frames within the csv file

1. have the same structure, i.e., the same number, names, and positions of columns
2. *and* the  monthly columns `V4`to `V8` refer to the same months 1 to 5 for all "sub frames".

*If this is true* then we can treat the whole csv file as one data frame and convert it to the desired format by reshaping using `melt()` and `dcast()` from the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df3)[, melt(.SD, id.vars = paste0("V", 1:3), na.rm = TRUE)][
  V3 != "month", dcast(.SD, V1 + V2 + rleid(variable) ~ forcats::fct_inorder(V3))][
    , setnames(.SD, 1:3, c("city", "address", "month"))]
```

> ```
>     city     address month      x    y      z       a    b       c
>  1:   la  63 main st     1     NA   NA     NA   87035  345   86690
>  2:   la  63 main st     2     NA   NA     NA 7467456  456 7467000
>  3:   la  63 main st     3     NA   NA     NA    3363  345    3018
>  4:   la  63 main st     4     NA   NA     NA     863  678     185
>  5:   la  63 main st     5     NA   NA     NA   43673  345   43328
>  6:  nyc 123 main st     1  58568 5345  53223      NA   NA      NA
>  7:  nyc 123 main st     2 567567 3673 563894      NA   NA      NA
>  8:  nyc 123 main st     3 567909 3453 564456      NA   NA      NA
>  9:  nyc 123 main st     4  35876 3467  32409      NA   NA      NA
> 10:  nyc 123 main st     5  56943  788  56155      NA   NA      NA
> 11:   sf 953 main st     1 457456   NA 452111      NA 5345      NA
> 12:   sf 953 main st     2   3455   NA   -218      NA 3673      NA
> 13:   sf 953 main st     3 345345   NA 341892      NA 3453      NA
> 14:   sf 953 main st     4  56457   NA  52990      NA 3467      NA
> 15:   sf 953 main st     5   3634   NA   2846      NA  788      NA
> ```

The `fct_inorder()` function from Hadley's `forcats` package is used here to order the columns by their first appearance instead of alphabetical order a, b, c, x, y, z.

Note that also the cities have been ordered alphabetically. If this is crcuial (but I doubt it is) the original order can be preserved as well by using

```
forcats::fct_inorder(V1) + V2 + rleid(variable) ~ forcats::fct_inorder(V3)
```

as `dcast()` formula.

#### Data

Unfortunately, the OP didn't supply the result of `dput(df3)` which made it unnecessarily difficult to reproduce the data set as printed in the question:

```
df3 <- readr::read_table(
  "     V1          V2    V3     V4      V5     V6      V7    V8
  1   nyc 123 main st month      1       2      3       4     5
  2   nyc 123 main st     x  58568  567567 567909   35876 56943
  3   nyc 123 main st     y   5345    3673   3453    3467   788
  4   nyc 123 main st     z  53223  563894 564456   32409 56155
  5                                                            
  6    la  63 main st month      1       2      3       4     5
  7    la  63 main st     a  87035 7467456   3363     863 43673
  8    la  63 main st     b    345     456    345     678   345
  9    la  63 main st     c  86690 7467000   3018     185 43328
  10                                                           
  11   sf 953 main st month      1       2      3       4     5
  12   sf 953 main st     x 457456    3455 345345   56457  3634
  13   sf 953 main st     b   5345    3673   3453    3467   788
  14   sf 953 main st     z 452111    -218 341892   52990  2846"
)
library(data.table)
setDT(df3)[, V2 := paste(X3, V2)][, c("X1", "X3") := NULL]
setDF(df3)[]
```

> ```
>     V1          V2    V3     V4      V5     V6    V7    V8
> 1  nyc 123 main st month      1       2      3     4     5
> 2  nyc 123 main st     x  58568  567567 567909 35876 56943
> 3  nyc 123 main st     y   5345    3673   3453  3467   788
> 4  nyc 123 main st     z  53223  563894 564456 32409 56155
> 5              NA            NA      NA     NA    NA    NA
> 6   la  63 main st month      1       2      3     4     5
> 7   la  63 main st     a  87035 7467456   3363   863 43673
> 8   la  63 main st     b    345     456    345   678   345
> 9   la  63 main st     c  86690 7467000   3018   185 43328
> 10             NA            NA      NA     NA    NA    NA
> 11  sf 953 main st month      1       2      3     4     5
> 12  sf 953 main st     x 457456    3455 345345 56457  3634
> 13  sf 953 main st     b   5345    3673   3453  3467   788
> 14  sf 953 main st     z 452111    -218 341892 52990  2846
> ```